# How do I only display a list when my data contains xyz (Specific)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

**Hi there,**
Ive been coding an app for my friend and me recently and currently I'm implementing Google Firebase's Firestore Database. I have set up a Data Model and a View Model to handle data to my view. Bear in mind I'm still new to Swift(UI) so my code might be a little messy.

This is where the database is accessed and the data is put into the data model.
Friends_Model.swift

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class Friends_Model: ObservableObject {
 
    
    @Published var friend_list = [Friends_Data]()
    @Published var noFriends = false
    
    func getData() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        db.collection("users").getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            
            //check for errors
            if error == nil {
                print("no errors")
                
                if let snapshot = snapshot {
                    
                    //Update the list property in main thread
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //get all docs and create friend list
                        
                            self.friend_list = snapshot.documents.map { d in
                                
                                    //Create friend item for each document
                                    return Friends_Data(id: d.documentID,
                                                        userID: d["userID"] as? String ?? "")
                            }
                    }
                }
                
            } else {
                // handle error
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

This is my data model. To my understanding this just sets the variables.
Friends_Data.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Friends_Data: Identifiable {
    

    var id: String
    var userID: String
}
```

This is my actual view where I output the data (just the relevant part ofc).
FriendsPanel.swift (Swift View File)

```
// var body etc. etc.
if let user = user {
            let uid = user.uid ?? "error: uid"
            let email = user.email ?? "error: email"
            let displayName = user.displayName
        
            VStack {
                Group{
                    Text("Your Friends")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                
                List (friends_model.friend_list) { item in
                    Text(item.userID)
                }
                .refreshable {
                    friends_model.getData()
                }
            }
// further code
```

Displaying all entries in the database works fine, though I'd wish to only display the entries with the attribute "friendsWith" having the same string as oneself (uid).

Something like

```
if friends_model.friends_list.userID == uid {
 // display List
} else {
 Text("You don't have any friends")
}
```

I couldn't work it out yet, although I've been going on and about for the past 2 hours now trying to solve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also sorry if I forgot to add anything.

Comment: Don't do this `DispatchQueue.main.async` within a firebase closure. UI calls are always done on the main thread and networking calls are on a background thread so it's not needed. And to your question; if you only want to retrieve and display a certain set of data, you would do that though a Firebase [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries). That will limit the results to only those you are interested in. As it is, you're loading everything within that collection. Last thing - the question is tagged the realtime database and you are actually using Firestore.

Comment: Hi @Jay. Thanks for the thoughtful comment. I'll remove the DispatchQueue. Also I did not find any other tag for the Firestore service.

Comment: The firestore tag is google-cloud-firestore. I fixed the tags for you. Check out @burnsi answer as it's the right one.

Comment: Will absolutely do... once I regain my sleep. Pretty late now in GMT+1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load only the data you need:

Use a query:

```
let queryRef = db.collection("users").whereField("friendsWith", isEqualTo: uid)
```

and then:

```
queryRef.getDocuments { snapshot, error in......
```

Here you can find more about firestore:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: I like the answer but what does `//unfortunately not for swift` mean and why is it in the answer.

Comment: I meant the documentation for the firestore. Follow the link. there are more examples of how to use firestore. But not for Swift.

Comment: Um. You should check the documentation, there's a Tab in each code Section marked "Swift" as well as "Web Version 9", "Objective C" etc.

Comment: You are right. It got google translated for me and it translated swift to a really weird term.

Comment: lol. Too funny. good answer, upvote for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a View that you init with `friends_model.friend_list` and store it in a `let friendList`. In that View you need an `onChange(of: friendList)` and then filter the list and set it on an `@State var filteredFriendList`. Then in the same view just do your `List(filteredFriendList) { friend in`

e.g.

```
struct FiltererdFriendView: View {
    let friendList: [Friend] // body runs when this is different from prev init.
    @State var filteredFriendList = [Friend]()

    // this body will run whenever a new friendList is supplied to init, e.g. after getData was called by a parent View and the parent body runs.
    var body: some View {
         List(filteredFriendList) { friend in
             ...
         }
         .onChange(of: friendList) { fl in
             // in your case this will be called every time the body is run but if you took another param to init that changed then body would run but this won't.
             filteredFriendList = fl.filter ...
         }
    }
}
```